# Alert if a website is either down or there is change in status

Tags: php, laravel

In my database i have notifications table that has URL to be checked and check frequency column and alert frequency column. what iam trying to do now with is code is. After sending a http request the code should able to do the following.

1. check if the website is up and if the status changed, then send notification . else do nothing.
2. if the website is down and if status changed, then send notification.
3. if the website is down and the status doesn't change  check the alert frequency. if the elapse_time is greater than the alert frequency, send notification.

that is what iam trying to achieve but failed to do some. my code need some improvement.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Utilities\Reporter;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use App\Notification;
use App\Status;
use App\Setting;
use Carbon;
class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    private $default_check_frequency;

    protected $client;

    protected $reporter;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client();

        $this->reporter = new Reporter;

        $this->default_check_frequency = Setting::defaultCheckFrequency();

        $this->default_alert_frequency = Setting::defaultAlertFrequency();
    }

    private function addStatusToNotification(Notification $notification, Status $status, $resCode)
    {
        $notification->statuses()->attach($status, [
            'values' => $resCode === 200
                ? 'up'
                : 'down'
        ]);
    }

    private function report(Notification $notification, $resCode)
    {
        /* how to send slack to different slach channels, now it is sending only to one channel!*/

        $this->reporter->slack($notification->website_url . ':' . '  is down' . ' this is the status code!' . ' @- ' .$resCode,
                               $notification->slack_channel);

        $this->reporter->mail($notification->email,$notification->website_url.' is down '. ' this is the status Code: '. $resCode);
    }

    private function sendNotification(Notification $notification, Status $status, $status_health, $frequency, $resCode)
    {
        $elapsed_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($status_health['timestamp'])->diffInMinutes();

        if ($elapsed_time >= $frequency) {
            $this->addStatusToNotification($notification, $status, $resCode);

            if ($resCode != 200) {
                $this->report($notification, $resCode);
            }
        }
    }

    public function status()
    {
        $notifications = Notification::where('active', 1)->get();

        $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();

        foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
            $this->updateStatus($notification, $status);
        }
    }

    private function updateStatus(Notification $notification, Status $status)
    {
        $resCode = $this->getStatusCode($notification->website_url);

        $this->sendNotification(
            $notification,
            $status,
            $notification->status('health'),
            $this->getFrequency($notification, $resCode),
            $resCode
        );
    }

    private function getFrequency(Notification $notification, $resCode)
    {

        switch ( $resCode) {
          case '200':
            return isset($notification->check_frequency)
            ? intval($notification->check_frequency)
            : $this->default_check_frequency;
            break;

          default:
            return isset($notification->alert_frequency)
            ? intval($notification->alert_frequency)
            : $this->default_alert_frequency;
            break;
        }
    }

    private function getStatusCode($url)
    {
        try {
            $response = $this->client->get($url, [
                'http_errors' => false
            ]);

            return $response->getStatusCode();

        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e) {

        }
    }
}
```

would you please help[ me with this problem. some thing is missed in my code?

Comment: Is this code throwing an error/exception? is this code not doing what is supposed to be doing? What exactly is your technical problem here? With what are we supposed to help?

Comment: don't make deamons like this in php...(reference https://software-gunslinger.tumblr.com/post/47131406821/php-is-meant-to-die) have a watcher deamon in a programming language that supports long running threads that polls the website, that updates a database. Then you can have a php/ajax combo to check the status in the database.

Comment: i hope my question is clear now. it doesn't through exception.

Comment: It might help you get better answers if you make sure you have a [mcve]. If you have a specific problem it is much easier to provide you with an answer.

Comment: ok. this code is able to send http request every 5 minutes. in case a web site is down, it sends a notification. then after 5 minutes, it will send the http request again, but if the website is still down, it should not send a notification. and it keeps on sending http request every 5 minut. once the status of one website is changed either from up to down or vise versa. it should able to send the notification again.

Comment: Okay, I understand the issue now :) What specifically is the problem? Does it keep sending the notification everytime or do you get an error? The 'Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example' means you can say 'This specific few lines of code produces this exact problem, how can I fix this problem?'